# C Compiler error with Lion and Newly Installed/Updated XCode

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, rvm

I am trying to set up RVM with Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and when I run

```
$rvm install 1.9.3
```

I get:

> ERROR: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/zkidd/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/zkidd/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/configure.log
>   ERROR: There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

And then when I open the configure.log in textmate I see:

> [2011-12-31 16:43:59]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/zkidd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/zkidd/.rvm/usr 
>   configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-libyaml-dir
>   checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
>   checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
>   checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
>   checking whether the C compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/Users/zkidd/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0':
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>   See`config.log' for more details

I'm not sure what to do next here :/  I have reinstalled XCODE and Mac OS is update to date.  Also, I just newly installed RVM too, which worked fine.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had very similar errors on 1.9.2 If ruby fails on its first attempt /Users/zkidd/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 can be left over once an installation fails. I would recommend removing ruby again (sorry...) and manually checking to see that that /Users/zkidd/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0 is deleted as well as the entire contents of .rvm/archives as ruby will not always overwrite files properly. The other option is to make sure that your file permissions are clean. I love the lazy way and just run fix file permissions in the disk utility. I'm pretty sure it's disk utility>startup disk>first aid>repair disk permissions.

That's what I've got... good luck!

Comment: I repaired my permissions -- a lot were broken.  But after trying again, it still did not work.  Do I need to remove ruby you think?

Comment: Can't hurt... When you remove it make sure to remove those two folders I mentioned above. That worked for me in the previous version

Comment: Ok. . . so lame/basic question. How should I remove?  I mean, I thought using RVM was so you did not have to remove Ruby.  Could you tell me the lines to type in terminal given that I have RVM running?

Comment: hmmm I actually just reread your post, and I don't believe your XCode is installed properly. in lion, if you download xcode from the appstore, it downloads and 'installs' an installer. you then have to select it in your /Applications folder to officially install it. I don't think rvm is even installing in the first place.

let me know if you find out anything from this. remember that xcode requires a reboot after install (just to cover all bases)